# How can I upload a video to a specific YouTube channel without using the OAuth URL?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, google-oauth

I have a problem that in theory should be easy, but I have been at this for days and just can't get it to work.

I have a Google account to which a few aliases are connected (The main gmail, a test thing I made a long time ago and a youtube channel). I render my videos on a cloud server and would like to then automatically upload them to this channel. I don't want to have to open the URL because this should work unattended. And by god, I can't figure it out. It's pretty baffling in how bad a state Google's official API docs are (or how dumb I am). I am using Python and Google's official client

So far, I've modified the python upload example from the python examples to incorporate service auth as described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount). This alone took me way too long to figure out, I think Google's newer key format is bugged. If I run this as is, I get a "youtubeSignupRequired" error, because the main account doesn't have a youtube channel. After hours of research I found [this link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#parameters) that pretty poorly describes the onBehalf parameters, but it seems these require a YouTube CMS account, which I don't have and I don't think I will get.

Am I missing something extremely obvious here? This seems like something that should not be hard to do at all.